# Как подключить CDMA модем- Убунту 11.04

Tags: ubuntu

Такая , вот , ситуёвина.  CDMA модем определяется  сразу , даже определяет провайдера. Есть в списке соединений, проблема , думаю в том, что нужно ввести  пин-код. А вот ввести его ни где не предлагается. То есть в винде при запуске появляется окошко с предложением ввести пин код, раньше на этот девайс шли дрова, но сборка как и убунта его сразу определила и всё спокойно заработало, а вот в убунте не хочет. Попытки с изменением соединения не к чему не привели- всё так же

Answer (score 1):

По проще поставить Network Manger последние версии очень хорошо заточины под 3g мопеды, кому так не интересно можно скриптами например comgt он же gcom

Comment: а в репах он есть? Скриптом, конечно интереснее, вот знать бы , что писать)))))

Comment: все что я перечислил в opensuse есть должны быть и в др. В comgt уже есть некоторые скрипты но придется повозится еще с ppp.

Answer (score 0):

Навскидку: возможно, пин-код прописывается в настроечных файлах. Прочтите внимательно инструкцию (man, описание в инете) к ПО, с помощью которого Убунта коннектится с провом и железом.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, у любого 3G модема с винды отключаем пин-код, далее прописываем точки доступа пароль и всё